# Unable to resolve path to module swiper/css

Tags: reactjs, less, swiper.js

I'm new to swiper and I'm currently facing problem importing these following css styles from Swiper:

```
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
```

I'm using Swiper version `6.8.4` because of some issue with `eslint`. I'm also using `lessjs` to style my page in `React`. So how do I solve this **Unable to resolve path to module** issue

Answer (score 1):

In v9.4.1 this is still present and the way you can resolve it is like:

```
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css';
import 'swiper/modules/pagination/pagination.min.css';
import 'swiper/modules/navigation/navigation.min.css';
```

EDIT:
Or you could include only the bundle css

```
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css';
```